# how to remove members of a list from a set

Tags: apex, salesforce-id, list, user, set

I have a Set made up of group members - but it includes members who are managers of group members.

I thought I could iterate over the set and for each member of the group query the user object manager field to see if it exists:

```
for (id thisId: result)    {
   string MgrId= [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE ManagerId =: result].Id; 

   if (MgrId=thisId){

      } 
}
```

But I will probably blow the governor SOQL limits doing it this way?

So what is the correct way to remove all the elements from my list `results` if they are the manager of another member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just used the below code and able to remove the users who are managers to other users.

```
Set<Id> setUserId = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> setManagerId = new Set<Id>();
for(User u : [select id from User]){
    setUserId.add(u.Id);
}
for(User u : [select id, ManagerId from User where ManagerId =: setUserId]){
    setManagerId.add(u.ManagerId);
}
system.debug(setUserId);
system.debug(setManagerId);
setUserId.removeAll(setManagerId);
system.debug(setUserId);
```

Here is the debug log

[image]

I have one system admin user, one standard user whose manager is the system admin users and a chatter user in my developer org.

Hope it helps.